Why do higher clock cycles generate more heat?
A CPU at a higher speed will generate more heat, essentially placing a limit on the maximum frequency. Higher speeds require more cooling, undervolting, etc.
While I always accepted this fact, I don't understand why this is the case. Whether you have one clock cycle a second or a billion, it doesn't change the fact that the CPU is powered on and consuming power for one second. If anything, the inductance inside the processor should limit the current if the speed is increased.
So why does energy consumption increase with clock speed?

the answer you linked to links to multiple good references for dynamic losses. Have you read those? Can you base your question on what you didn't understand about the answer and their links?

The number of transitions do indeed make a large difference.  Every clock transition requires energy to charge and discharge the stray circuit capacitances (which is the main process that consumes power).  Thus the more times you do this in a second, the more power the processor requires.  That is why high GHz processors with multi-cores can consume several tens of watts.
If the processor is put in a sleep state with the clock stopped, then only the small leakage current is required to power the processor.

There are two ways a digital circuit consumes power.
There is static consumption which is basically leakage through the circuit at DC even when nothing is being clocked or switching.
There is dynamic consumption which is consuming power when a transistor switches. The power is being dissipated in the transistor resistances as the transistors are not ideal switches. The resistances charge capacitive structures such as FET gates and stray capacitances as any conductors separated by an insulator is a capacitor. Also during a transition of logic state there is a brief moment where both CMOS transistors are halfway on, which creates a resistive path directly between supply voltage and ground.
So every time a single logic gate such as an inverter switches from one state to another, there is a surge of power consumed and being converted to heat.
So with a faster clock rate, more power is being consumed per second.
The problem is also twofold, as the clock rates increase, you need to be able to switch the transistors faster, and for that you need to increase the voltage so the capacitances are charged faster.
So the power consumption is approximated to be linearly proportional to switching frequency, the switching capacitance, and number of transistors switching per clock.
Unfortunately going faster requires increasing the voltage, and the power consumption is squarely proportional to voltage.
This is why the transistors are made small to minimize the switching capacitance, but then small transistors leak more static current even when they are not switching.
So that's why balancing between power consumption and performance is difficult, you generally need to control the frequency to match the required computational load, which allows you to also control the supply voltage lower to still be able to run at that frequency, and then you need to still decide what size transistors are most effective to have a good balance between static consumption at that voltage versus dynamic consumption at that voltage and frequency.
